# ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER makes ContentResolver query crash

Tags: android, crash

I am trying to send an implicit intent to my contacts app for the user to select a contact. My app will then extract that contact's name and phone number for use in the app.

(Note: I'm on Chapter 21 of BigNerdRanch's Android book, doing the challenge so there's no answer key. I looked on their [inactive] forums and couldn't find an explanation for this bug.)

So at first the book tutorial had it working where the query only contained the name. But when I tried to add another column for the phone number, it would crash every time I selected a contact and thus was in the process of returning to the original activity that sent the implicit intent.

I thought maybe it crashed because my contact I selected did not have a phone number stored with it? So I tried one with a phone number AND a name, and it still crashed.

Here is the code, all with the same class (which extends a support fragment). Thanks for any help!

FWIW: Here is the page where you can download the solution for chapter 21 here http://www.bignerdranch.com/we-write/android-programming , which shows basically all the code I have except what I altered to do the challenge problem.

onCreateView(...):

```
...
mSuspectButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_suspectButton);
        mSuspectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CONTACT);
            }
        });
        if(mCrime.getSuspect() != null) {
            mSuspectButton.setText(mCrime.getSuspect());
        }

        mDialButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_dialButton);
        if(mCrime.getPhoneNumber() == null) {
            mDialButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        mDialButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, mCrime.getPhoneNumber());
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
```

onActivityResult:

When the code is like this, it crashes.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACT) {
        Uri contactUri = data.getData();
            //Specify which fields you want your query to return values for.
            String[] queryFields = new String[] {

                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER
            };

            //Perform your query - the contactUri is like a "where" clause here
            Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactUri, queryFields, null, null, null);

            //Double-check that you actually got results
            if (c.getCount() == 0) {
                c.close();
                return;
            }

            //Pull out the first column of the first row of data - that is your suspect's name.
            c.moveToFirst();
            Log.d(TAG, "" + c.getColumnCount());
            String suspect = c.getString(0);
            String phoneNumber = "1"; //c.getString(1);  
            mCrime.setSuspect(suspect);
            mCrime.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
            if(mCrime.getPhoneNumber() == null) {
                mDialButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            mSuspectButton.setText(suspect);

            c.close();


        }
```

NOTE: In this line

```
String phoneNumber = "1"; //c.getString(1);
```

It is supposed to be "c.getString(1)", but I was testing any number to see if it would still crash, and it still did.

When I replace the query with this,

```
String[] queryFields = new String[] {

                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
            };
```

then it works just fine, and does not crash.

LogCat:

```
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212): Process: com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent, PID: 20212
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65539, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/133r155-3D2F5537/155 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.CrimePagerActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column number
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column number
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:413)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:461)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:404)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.CrimeFragment.onActivityResult(CrimeFragment.java:618)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:166)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
05-19 18:38:38.462: E/AndroidRuntime(20212):    ... 11 more
05-19 18:38:40.382: D/Lexi(20281): {"location":"provo","age":"22","name":"Lexi"}
05-19 18:38:40.422: I/Adreno-EGL(20281): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
05-19 18:38:40.442: D/OpenGLRenderer(20281): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code you will get a phone number.

```
Uri contactUri = data.getData();

                Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactUri,
                        null, null, null, null);

                if (c.getCount() == 0) {
                    c.close();
                    return;
                }

                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String name = c
                            .getString(c
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String phoneNumber = c
                            .getString(c
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                    String contactId = c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    if (phoneNumber.equals("1")) {
                        Cursor phones = getActivity()
                                .getContentResolver()
                                .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                        null,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                                + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                            phoneNumber = phones
                                    .getString(phones
                                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        }
                        phones.close();
                    }
                    Log.d("Stack",
                            name + " " + " " + phoneNumber + " "
                                    + c.getColumnCount());
                }
                c.close();
```

**Note :-Actually you are trying to pull a data form column (column name "number")  which is not present in "ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI" that's why got an exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column number
.**

Comment: Is there a way to get the phone number with implicit permission, similar to how my code only gets one contact's info? It doesn't need "READ_CONTACTS" permission, but this solution does require it.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite late but I believe there is an better and clean alternative to the problem you're facing. Simply add the following lines to your code.

```
String SELECTION = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER "='1'";
Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactUri, queryFields, SELECTION, null, null);
```

The selection argument `HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = 1` makes sure that you only retrieve those contacts which have at least 1 phone number. So the illegal column index exception will not occur.